# How can I take a char as user input and store it to a register WITHOUT using any pseudo instructions in RISC-V?

Tags: assembly, riscv

I'm trying to get a char from user input in RISC-V, but the limitations of the assignment say I cannot use any pseudo instructions other than "la". Every example I've found uses "li" or some other pseudo-instruction I'm not allowed to use. Please help!

Here's what I have so far:

```
    addi a7, zero, 12
    ecall
```

Comment: Does that work for you?

Comment: FYI, you can use pseudo instructions (like `li`), and then assemble the code to see what real instruction(s) the assembler uses for those.

Comment: Under what OS?  Or what simulator environment?  RARS?  Real OSes have system calls like POSIX `read(int fd, void *buf, size_t len)` that copy into user-space memory and take a pointer + count, because a system call that could only read one byte per call has way too much overhead.  And there's no need to have a special system call just for "the terminal".  So I assume this is RARS or something which provides a toy environment with a set of `ecall` services that are like some simplified C library functions, but without error status.  RISC-V includes more than this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
addi a7, zero, 12 # System call for getting user input
ecall
addi %reg, a0, 0 # Load input from a0 into given register
print_newline
```

The input goes straight to a0 register, so you can move it into whatever register you want from there.